# Grails error installing searchable plugin

Tags: grails-plugin

When I try to install the searchable plugin in a grails app, I'm told that grails can't resolve the following dependencies:

```
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :: org.grails.plugins#searchable;0.6.3: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.AbstractResolver.initRepositoryCacheManagerFromSettings(AbstractResolver.java:396)
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Grails version is 2.0.3

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install it from a zip file? This might be caused by [GRAILS-9006](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9006?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel), which prevents plugins from being installed via a local directory, to be fixed in Grails 2.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncommenting the mavenCentral line in BuildConfig.groovy then try the install-plugin again.

```
    //mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    //mavenRepo...
```